# Autoplay blocking on Safari

Tags: javascript, video, safari, observers, autoplay

I have this snippet of code that starts the video as soon as the video enters the screen. the problem is that it doesn't work on safari, leaving the video completely black and giving me this error: "Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user permission denied .".

```
<video class="tuttiVideo" loop muted preload="none">
    <source class="source_video" src="xxx" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

```
  function observerCallback(entries, observer) {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
        console.log("pausa")
        entry.target.pause();
        playState = false;
      } else {
        console.log("play")
        entry.target.play();
        playState = true;
      }
    });
  };


  window.onload = () => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(observerCallback);
    var videoStart = document.querySelectorAll(".tuttiVideo")
    let playState = null;
    console.log("sono qui")
    videoStart.forEach((i) => {
      if (i) {
        observer.observe(i);
      }
    });
  }
```

I already tried excluding safari by adding

```
var isSafari = /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
```

and putting everything inside an if, but I keep having the same problem.

Could anyone help me?

(I'm sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 0):

try adding playsinline

```
<video class="tuttiVideo" loop muted preload="none" playsinline>
```

you can also capture a touch event as Safari could require at least one user trigger before programmatically play pause different media

```
window.addEvenetListener('touchstart', ()=>{
  // trigger play
})
```

also referencing https://stackoverflow.com/a/42236446/13365797